# Python: Robinhood_Stocks module's order_buy_market function returning error

Tags: python, python-3.x, finance, trading

I am using the below code to send a buy order to Robinhood's API in Python. But it is giving an error message. I tried two ways to execute the buy order

**Method 1**

**Code**:
import robin_stocks.robinhood as rs
rs.orders.order_buy_fractional_by_quantity('AAPL',10)

**Error message**:
{'non_field_errors': ['Your app version is missing important stock trading updates. You can still place orders on the web.']}

**Method 2**

**Code**:
import robin_stocks.robinhood as rs
rs.order_buy_market('NOK',2)

**Error message**:
{'non_field_errors': {'non_field_errors': ['Invalid Good Til Canceled order.']}

I am not sure what is the solution to fix this issue.

I was expecting the code to execute the buy order as is mentioned in multiple articles online.